# iPhone 4s is locked after updating to iOS 8

Tags: iphone

I updated my iPhone 4s to iOS 8. Now my iPhone is locked, showing the iTunes icon and power cord picture. I tried to hold down buttons but it won't unlock. How do I unlock it?

Comment: It wants you to plug it in to a Mac/PC running iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

The "Tunes icon and power cord picture" means the iPhone needs to be plugged into a computer running iTunes, and that should allow the system to finish whatever it needs to finish.